# python-Don't want the inside tag to be crawled

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to crawl a website.

```
<time class="poster-card__date"> "Wed 16"
  <span class="event-time">7:00 PM</span>
</time>
```

The part of python code is like this:

```
for event_date in soup.findAll('time',{'class':"poster-card__date"}):
        print(str(event_date.text))
```

Now the thing is that the output I am getting for all event is like this:

```
Wed 167:00 PM
```

I want to crawl them differently. Actually, here I want to ignore the time of the event and only print the date part, i.e the inside `<span>` tag should not be considered. And the desirable output for all events should be like:

```
Wed 16
```

Comment: BS cannot crawl, only parse HTML

Comment: value of event_date.next is "Wed 16"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) to get the content of the tag,

```
>>> for event_date in soup.findAll('time',{'class':"poster-card__date"}):
...         print(str(event_date.contents[0])),
...
 "Wed 16"
```